# How can I create a moving graphic in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, ascii

I am a first year university student and for my Java tutorial we have been asked to design a group project working with animated ASCII graphics. So far we have created the individual frames as text files and uploaded them to our program.

This allows users to move through the frames using the arrow keys, however I know there is a way to create a timed separator between the frames that moves through them automatically (essentially creating a movie).

Does anyone know how to code that frame? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: *"ASCII graphics"* What exactly is ASCII graphics?  I've heard of [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), but this sounds different.  ASCII art would generally be reserved for command line apps. with no GUI, or for printing.  Are you coding a (Swing/AWT/SWT) GUI for the app.?

Answer (score 4):

Place your frames in a list or array and iterate through them. Also add a `Thread.sleep(..)` to pause between the frames.

Answer (score 0):

Put the picture cycling in a loop

```
    //Set your int and start a loop for how many times you want the movie to cycle
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        try {  
            //Load First picture then sleep for 1 second
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)
            //Load Second picture then sleep for 1 second
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)
        } catch(InterruptedException e){ 
            //Perform your exception handling
        } 
        //Increase the int so we aren't stuck here forever
        i++
    }
```

If you are looking at a really long list of pictures you will probally want to use a list or an array as suggested in the other answers.